# Read Only Folders on Windows

Tags: windows, java, file-permissions

I'm trying to mark a folder read-only using Java. The function call is setWritable(false). But, this doesn't disallow creation of a new file in that folder. I've read about this a lot and it turns out that Windows doesn't consider the read-only flag on folders. 
Is there any solution that can be used to mark a folder read-only in the sense it would behave as on, say, Linux?
[I have already asked this on stackoverflow and one user suggested to try here on superuser.]

Comment: Original question on Stack Overflow at http://stackoverflow.com/q/30797831/486504

Comment: **Please don't simply re-post questions on other sites in the network.** If a question is a better fit on another site, instead, "flag" it for moderator attention and request migration. Reposting causes duplication of both content and effort, which is something the Stack Exchange network in general tries very hard to avoid.

Comment: I did mention this in my question itself. And I shall make sure to ask for migration next time. :)

Comment: @SachinGoel: The proper way to do it in Windows is to deny [create file permission](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to first construct an application and take into account the harmful actions that are using your application, you can potentially make.

Then take into account the constraints of the programming language, in this case java, to reject those methods that interact with the system directly through the server part of the application.

Understand that some techniques - such as exhibiting the attributes are not read-protected.

Good design, in this case, in my opinion -

1. The virtual file system that will protect the file system of the operating system from direct user intervention
2. server commands, for example, based on SOAP, which will be approved by the server to send part of the team
3. The language of the client-side operating system that will execute commands with SOAP server

This is a minimal skeleton application. Then you can add a virtual file system indexing, and other useful features.

Yes, you can solve these problems directly using JavaFX or JNI.

But it is a dangerous way in terms of safety.

And a dead end road in terms of the further development of the application.

Among other things, you can decide using JNI, but simple things for system programming languages ​​or languages ​​.Net applications or administrative scripting java to be very complicated.

Which brings us to unnecessary complication of the design process.

Comment: It's not about the application or programming language at all. The code I'm working on has a Unit test which tests that the directory be set read-only. Since it is part of a bigger project, I cannot let go of the Test requirement. It works fine on Mac and Linux but the file system permission on Windows lead to a failure. I was looking for a work-around to this. I have no problem adding some platform specific code in there, just that if I could figure it out at least.

Comment: @SachinGoel - So do a test to determine which OS the program is on, and based on that result, run a different unit test.  Your going to HAVE to change the unit test, because, Windows is not Unix/Linux.